# Django, changing the default location of settings.py or use another file

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set a new structure for settings.py in my django app. ( Django 1.7b4 - python 3.3.2 )

```
- manage.py
- mainapp
  -- wsgi.py
  -- urls.py
  -- settings
     --- __init__.py
     --- common.py
     --- development.py
     --- production.py
```

I have changed manage.py and wsgi.py as

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mainapp.settings.common")
```

But i got an 'Empty Secret Key Error'. Because django still tries to find settings inside mainapp.settings ( which is default ) and looks inside the empty **init**.py file...

In my mac os terminal i checked and changed DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable... But nothing changes. Django always search in default location.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable for your web server.  In the case of apache this takes the form:

```
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mainapp.settings.common
```

I've added this in my virtualhost configuration and it works great

If you are using the development server (runserver) you can specify a custom settings module:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=mainapp.settings.common
```

Comment: where to add this... In my virtual env folder i have bin, lib, include?

Comment: It depends how you are running the app: are you in the development phase just now and using runserver? or are you serving the site via apache2+mod_wsgi?

Comment: I am using eclipse ide and i am in development stage. And another problem is when i set an env var via terminal and runserver via eclipse i can not get the env var that i set

Comment: I'm not familiar with eclipse, but when using runserver you can specify the settings module to use. I've updated my answer to show how this is done.